# Attempting to Base64 encode this variable

Tags: python, base64

I'm trying to encode the 'username' variable into Base64, then write it into a text file, and finally decode the Base64, and read/print it.

```
while True:

username = input("What is your username?: ")

file = open("newfile.txt", "w")
file.write(base64.b64encode(username))
file.close

file = open("newfile.txt", "r")
file.read(base64.b64decode(username))
break
```

> -TypeError- 'str' does not support the buffer interface

What I did here seemed the most logical out of what I've seen.

I am fairly new to Python, and have tried all the method's I've seen online to Base64 encode a variable, and none have worked.

Comment: 1) You're not writing anything to the file and 2) there's no trace of your attempts with base64 or the specific problems you encountered.

Comment: Sorry, I'm fairly new this. I've updated it anyways.

Comment: And do you get any specific errors?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/--", line 18, in <module>
    file.write(base64.b64encode(username))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\base64.py", line 62, in b64encode
    encoded = binascii.b2a_base64(s)[:-1]
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

Comment: FYI: `file.read(base64.b64decode(username))` means *take `username`, `b64decode` it, then `read` the `file` with it*.....!?!

Comment: If I write to the file the encoded base64 variable, shouldn't I have to decode it before reading?

Comment: @user3205119: You can't decode what you haven't read yet!  The decoding happens *after* reading.

Comment: Also, you forgot the parentheses in `file.close()`.

Comment: I see what you mean, however I'm curious to see what's wrong with my encoding / decoding. What is giving the errors?

Comment: The base64 encoding error is because in Python3 you need to pass [base64.b64encode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html) a _byte_ string, not a normal Unicode string. But as others have said  there are various other problems with your posted code, including that it's not indented properly.

Answer (score 0):

base64 expects and returns bytes (in python3); but strings must be written to files. here the example with explicit writing and more compact reading:

```
import base64

while True:

    username_str = input("What is your username?: ")

    with open("newfile.txt", "w") as file_handler:
        username_bytes = bytes(username_str, 'utf-8')
        b64_bytes = base64.b64encode(username_bytes)
        b64_str = b64_bytes.decode('utf-8')
        file_handler.write(b64_str)
        # file_handler.close()
        # close not needed inside the context handler
    with open("newfile.txt", "r") as file_handler:        
        print(base64.b64decode(bytes(file_handler.read(), 'utf-8')).decode('utf-8'))
    break
```

btw: file is a reserved keyword and should not be used as variable.